# How to remove IE compatibility mode from iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, visualforce, apex, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a VisualForce page which runs in IE 8 compatibility mode, and we have an iframe on top of that VF Page. How to detect and remove the IE compatibility from iframe only (basically in JS).
I tried searching the compatibility mode for iframe by

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('X-UA-Compatible')
```

but it returned null.

Comment: You can't, the document mode is consistent throughout all of the windows.

Comment: So you mean that I have to remove compatibility mode from parent page then it will reflect in iframe ?

Comment: Yep. Hmm... they've messed up MSDN again, I can't find it just now, but I'd recall consistent document mode came along with IE8, older versions allow inconsistent document modes.